# Is $\sin (e^{x^2} + \cos(3x^{2} + 5))$ on $[0, 1]$ uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing

$f(x) = \sin (e^{x^2} + \cos(3x^{2} + 5))$ on $[0, 1]$ uniformly continuous because:

Proof: $f(x)$ is a continuous function on $[0, 1]$, which is a closed interval, so $f$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, 1].$ 
$\square$

This is basically the uniform continuity theorem. Would this suffice? Do I have to prove that the function is continuous on $[0, 1]$ or would it be obvious to the grader since $sin$ function is continuous on $[0, 1]$?

Comment: Heine-Cantor theorem, is a name people use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that your current answer would suffice - the question appears to be searching for an abstract answer, like you give, rather than more mundane proofs of continuity. One thing to note, however, is that you are using that $\sin$ is continuous on $\mathbb R$, not just on $[0,1]$ - notice that the argument to the sine function might vary beyond just that interval, even though $x$ does not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes your argument is correct, you can also conclude the same by using the fact that $f'$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and hence $f$ is Lipschitz implying uniform continuity.